# Change the format of one letter of one entry in the list of abbreviations

Tags: fonts, glossaries, acronyms, italic

I use the `acronym` package to so the list of abbreviations. One of the entries needs to have one italic letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,toc, nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long3col, title=\centerline{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}, toctitle=List of Abbreviations, nonumberlist=true]
\newacronym{test}{TEST}{\textit{italicPart} normal-format part}
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glossaries` package requires a fairly specific sequence of command invocations to work. Here is a modified example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% we must invoke pdflatex, then makeglossaries, then pdflatex again. 
% arara is not required for this but convenient.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries  % like makeindex

% entries should be defined in the preamble
\newacronym{test}{TEST}{\textit{italicPart} normal-format part}
\newacronym{foo}{FOO}{fried omelette obsession}

\begin{document}

% but defining entries is not enough - we also need to add them
% to the output 
get the entry into the glossary: \glsadd{test}

if we omit this, as we do with the defined entry FOO, we won't see it in the output. 

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long3col, title=\centerline{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}, toctitle=List of Abbreviations, nonumberlist=true]
\end{document}
```

The `glossaries` package is very powerful, but also complex. Sometimes it may be more straightforward to just manually write the acronyms into a `description` environment or table.